# Why running go api's on docker give response when hit with the postman?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker file in the named `docker-compose.yml` in the bkapiv folder and there is a service of `users` and I run the docker-compose.yml file by command `sudo docker-compose up -d` and then I run `sudo docker run users/image` and then I run my database using `sudo docker-compose up -d` and then `sudo docker run mongo` both were started. But now I will hit the route based on `port:8080` the route will not respond me any valid output it will show me `Could not not get any response` my `docker-compose.yml` is given below:-

```
version: '2'
 services:
  web:
   build: ./users
   ports:
    - "8080:8080"

users:
  image: cinema/movies
  container_name: cinema-movies
  depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: movies.local
db:
   image: mongo
   container_name: users_db
   ports:
     - "27019:27019"
   volumes:
     - ./backup:/backup:rw
```

Folder Structure is:-

```
 bkapiv(Folder)------users(Folder)
   |                  |
   |                   ------Dockerfile
   |
    ---------docker-compose.yml
```

And the url hitting on the postman is `movies.local/users` method `POST` but it will show me `COULD NOT GET ANY RESPONSE`.

How I will resolve it and send the data to through my go api to the mongodb

Answer (score 0):

In your docker-compose file you are exposing the container port 8000 to host port 8000. Not 8080!

Comment: I changes it to `8080` and trying to hit the route then it will give no response again